# Cannot call method 'html' of undefined error while trying to parse a template

Tags: backbone.js

IM trying to bind a template to a Backbone view like this:

```
SearchView = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function () {
    this.render();
  },
  render: function(){
    var template = _.template( $("#search_template").html(), {});
    this.$el.html(template);
  }
});

var search_view = new SearchView({ el: $("#search_container") });
```

But im always getting the error:  Cannot call method 'html' of undefined

What am I missing here?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lmartins/hhpSV/

Thanks.

Comment: Your jsfiddle is empty. When do you call `var search_view = new SearchView({ el: $("#search_container") });`? In the document ready?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, pretty basic mistake.
I was creating a model instead of a view.

The first line should be:

```
SearchView = Backbone.View.extend({
```